# CreateTransaction in blockcypher/php-client

Tags: php, api

### Create a transaction. (all balance  - Fees embedded)

How to create a transaction with a fee embedded(All Balance)? [blockcypher/php-client](https://github.com/blockcypher/php-client)

```
/// Tx inputs
$input = new \BlockCypher\Api\TXInput();
$input->addAddress("n3D2YXwvpoPg8FhcWpzJiS3SvKKGD8AXZ4");

/// Tx outputs
$output = new \BlockCypher\Api\TXOutput();
$output->addAddress("mvwhcFDFjmbDWCwVJ73b8DcG6bso3CZXDj");
$output->setValue(10000000); // Satoshis (all balance)

/// Tx
$tx = new \BlockCypher\Api\TX();
$tx->addInput($input);
$tx->addOutput($output);

#Code ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$output->setValue(-1);
```

> If you want to automatically empty your input address(es) without
>   knowing their exact value, your TX request object's value can be set
>   to -1 to sweep all value from your input address(es) to your output
>   address. Please be advised that this only works with a single output
>   address.